# Leap Motion for Processing scaleFactor function

Tags: java, processing, leap-motion

I am using Leap Motion with processing utilising the Leap Motion for Processing library. ([Leap Motion for Processing Lib](https://github.com/voidplus/leap-motion-processing/tree/beta))

I am however struggling to find a way to use scaleFactor as seen in Java Leap Motion documentation. ([Java Api Docs](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/api/Leap.Frame.html#javaclasscom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_frame_1a4c83c02df68b033d406e6c773b7f495e))

I want to access this functionality in order to create a zoom function in my application when moving hands away from each other.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue in the form of an alternative library. It means I will have to recode the gestures I have already created due to the libraries working differently but I do now have access to the Frame class which I was missing before.

This is the library I am now using... https://github.com/heuermh/leap-motion-processing

Below is a simple snippet of code which shows the scaleFactor working...

```
import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Frame;
import com.leapmotion.leap.processing.LeapMotion;

LeapMotion leapMotion;

float zoomFactor = 0;

void setup()
{
size(16 * 50, 9 * 50);
background(20);
frameRate(30);

leapMotion = new LeapMotion(this);
}

void draw()
{
fill(20);
rect(0, 0, width, height);
fill(200);
rect(0, 0, (zoomFactor * 100), (zoomFactor * 100));
}


 void onFrame(final Controller controller)
{
Frame frame = controller.frame();
Frame sinceFrame = controller.frame(25);
zoomFactor = frame.scaleFactor(sinceFrame);
println(zoomFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick glance through the processing library that you are using and it didn't look like it exposes the scale factor or other motion attributes from the Leap Motion Frame class (which is where you would get the scale factor for two-handed motion). That's not a library created or maintained by Leap Motion. I suspect your options are to use the Leap Motion Java library directly or to get the feature added to the processing library you are using.

It looks like you would add the feature you are trying to use in LeapMotion.java -- but you should discuss this with the developer who created the library.

Comment: This is what I feared! I couldn't see it anywhere in the library, I will try to find an alternative library and report back as I suspect getting the Frame class added (if possible) would take too long and out of my timeframe for this project.